# how to get selected item value of a DataGridHyperlinkColumn in wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am using a normal data grid column like

I am getting the value using
var item = datagrid1.SelectedItem;
 var a=  datagrid1.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text

But instead Of normal datagrid text column if I am using DataGridTextColumn  it is giving the value as ""; why? and How can i get the value;

Answer (score 0):

What are you populating your datagrid with? I usually use this method I created that gets the value from the data context and not the grid itself.

```
private Tuple<string,int,string,int> SelectedCell(System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid dataGrid, int textIndex, int valueIndex)
    {            
        string cellText = null, cellValue = null;

        //if the text index is out of bounds, fix it
        if (dataGrid.SelectedCells.Count < textIndex)
        {
            textIndex = dataGrid.SelectedCells.Count - 1;
        }
        else if (textIndex < 0)
        {
            textIndex = 0;
        }

        //if the value index is out of bounds, fix it
        if (dataGrid.SelectedCells.Count < valueIndex)
        {
            valueIndex = dataGrid.SelectedCells.Count - 1;
        }
        else if (valueIndex < 0)
        {
            valueIndex = 0;
        }

        System.Data.DataRowView row = dataGrid.SelectedItem as System.Data.DataRowView;

        if(row != null)
        {
            cellText = row[textIndex].ToString();
            cellValue = row[valueIndex].ToString();
        }

        return new Tuple<string,int,string,int>(cellText,textIndex, cellValue, valueIndex);
    }
```

It gets the values of 2 indexes (column indexes) and then returns those values as well as the index of those values in case the original indexes were out of bounds.